# npm err missing script lint when deploying

Tags: node.js, npm

When running the following command:

```
npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint
```

It returns the following error:

> `npm ERR! missing script: lint`
>
> `npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:`
>
> `npm ERR! C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-13T01_27_59_009Z-debug.log`
>
> `Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1`

This is my `package.json`:

```js
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.12.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You are trying to run the `lint` task, but it doesn't exist in your package definition. Are you sure you're not wanting to run the following (based on your question title)?

```
npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run deploy
```

Edit: ok, looks like Firebase expects a lint script. So just add `"lint": ""` to your scripts.

Comment: No i was just deploying functions and i got this error.
I just wrote:
Firebase deploy
And got this error

npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint
npm ERR! missing script: lint

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR! C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-13T01_27_59_009Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1

Answer (score 3):

the linter package isn't installed , if you need to deploy without run linter
you can remove the those lines from firebase.json file

```
 "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
```

Answer (score 2):

I was getting same error while deploying firebase cloud functions written in typescript. Under package.json, I added following lines. Then the function got deployed successfully.

under scripts ->

```
"lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
```

Under devDependencies ->

```
"tslint": "^5.12.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replace $RESOURCE_DIR with %RESOURCE_DIR% in your firebase.json file.